# Cannot assign values to array of pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I want to copy my array over to a pointer, so I can sort the array without changing the original. I'm not getting any errors, and am at a dead end. I've tried printing the pointer's contents, but it's always junk data. If anyone could help me it'd be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubbleSort(char *array[], int arrIndex);
void displaySort (char *array[], int arrIndex);

int main (void)
{
    int index;
    int count = 0;
    
    printf("Enter number of people (0 - 50): ");
    scanf("%d", &index);
    index -= 1;
    
    char userLastFirst[25][index];
    int userAge[index];
    //defining pointer
    char *namePtr[25][index];
    
    //do while loop, loops while count is less than or equal to the index
    do{
        printf("Enter name %d (last, first): ", count);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", userLastFirst[count]);
        printf("Enter age %d: ", count);
        scanf("%d", &userAge[count]);
        
    //  printf("\n\n%s %d\n\n", userLastFirst[count], userAge[count]);
        
        count++;
    } while (count <= index);
    
    //assigning values to pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        namePtr[25][i] = &userLastFirst[25][i];
    }
    //does not print values of pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        printf("value of ptr[%d] = %s\n", i, namePtr[i]);
    }
    
    bubbleSort(*namePtr, index);
    
    displaySort(*namePtr, index);
    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(char *array[], int arrIndex)
{
   for (unsigned int pass = 0; pass < arrIndex - 1; ++pass) {
      for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex - 1; ++i) {
         if (array[i] < array[i + 1]) {
            int temp = *array[i];
            *array[i] = *array[i + 1];
            *array[i + 1] = temp;
         }
      }
   }
}

void displaySort(char *array[], int arrIndex)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++){
        printf("%s",*array[i]);
    }
}
```

Sorry it's a lot, but I've looked everywhere, and am not exactly sure what the problem is. I suspect it's how I pass pointers thru the functions, or how I'm using `*` and `&` but am not totally sure what I'm doing wrong. The for loop below the one that assigns the array values to the pointer is for testing. It's supposed to print out the values I had given it in the previous for loop, but it doesn't. It just prints junk data.

Comment: are you expecting `namePtr[25][i] = &userLastFirst[25][i];` to copy the names?

Comment: inkystinky33, Why did you code an `s` in `" %[^\n]s"`?  What text or who suggested that?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues here, and since I don't know what exactly you want your final code to look like, I am going to give a few examples of what is wrong and how you could possibly fix that.

```c
char userLastFirst[25][index];
```

This should be

```c
char userLastFirst[index][25];
```

You don't want 25 people with names up to *index* characters in them, but rather *index* people with names up to 25 characters int them.

```c
char *namePtr[25][index];
```

should be

```c
char namePtr[index][25];
```

Same as before + you don't need the * here. Since you decided to go with vla let's stick with it. You would use * and more specifically `char **` if you went with `malloc`/`calloc`.

```c
namePtr[25][i] = &userLastFirst[25][i];
```

rather than doing this awkward copying, try:

```c
strcpy(namePtr[i], userLastFirst[i]);
```

it copies the entire string for you, rather than just a single character. You will need to `#include` the `<string.h>` library for that.

```c
void bubbleSort(char *array[], int arrIndex)
```

The first bubble sort argument should be:

```c
char array[][25] // the same in displaySort
```

if you want to do it without the hassle of `malloc`/`calloc`.
And also don't go with `int` as your `temp` type. Rather do `char temp[25]` and copy them around with `strcpy`.
And don't compare strings with `<`, it doesn't work in C. Use `strcmp` for that.
And that's it for doing it without `malloc`/`calloc`, here's an example code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void bubbleSort(char array[][25], int size);
void displaySort(char array[][25], int size);

int main (void)
{
    int num_of_people;

    printf("Enter number of people (0 - 50): ");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_people);

    char original_array[num_of_people][25];
    char copied_array[num_of_people][25];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_people; i++) {
        printf("Enter name %d (last, first): ", i);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", original_array[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num_of_people; i++){
        strcpy(copied_array[i], original_array[i]);
    }

    bubbleSort(copied_array, num_of_people);
    displaySort(copied_array, num_of_people);
    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(char array[][25], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; ++j) {
            if (strcmp(array[j], array[j + 1]) > 0) {
                char temp[25];
                strcpy(temp, array[j]);
                strcpy(array[j], array[j + 1]);
                strcpy(array[j + 1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

void displaySort(char array[][25], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%s\n",array[i]);
    }
}
```

and the program work like this:

```c
Enter number of people (0 - 50): 4
Enter name 0 (last, first): Kowalski, Jan
Enter name 1 (last, first): Kowalska, Anna
Enter name 2 (last, first): Nowak, Miłosz
Enter name 3 (last, first): Amper, Ohm
Amper, Ohm
Kowalska, Anna
Kowalski, Jan
Nowak, Miłosz
```

I hope this is something you wanted to achieve.

Comment: You are incredible. Thank you SO much! I know I have much to learn, but I've definitely learned a lot from this. Especially the ordering of the elements in the string, and of course the whole pointer business. I've been struggling with C recently because of pointers. I'll try my best to master them. It's hard to write and tell people what you want to happen, because I think everyone knows what I want to happen. That's something I'll have to learn.  I hope to know C as well as you do one day. Thanks again :D (And yes, this is exactly what I wanted)